# Using "\b" in a .NET regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Can someone explain me why results 1,2 and 3 are false? Looks like a trivial problem.. but still, I'm stuck :/

```
        string input = "foo abc defg bar";
        string pattern = "abc defg";

        string pattern1 = "\b" + Regex.Escape(pattern) + "\b";
        string pattern2 = "\b" + pattern + "\b";
        string pattern3 = "\babc defg\b";
        string pattern4 = pattern;


        bool result1 = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern1); // FALSE
        bool result2 = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern2); // FALSE
        bool result3 = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern3); // FALSE
        bool result4 = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern4); // TRUE
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. Your `\b` is actually the backspace character, not the regex `\b`. You need to either use `"\\b"` to embed this in a C# string literal, or use verbatim string literals: `@"\b"`.

Remember: The backslash is an escape character for C# strings just as it is for regex, so if you're not careful, you need to escape things twice, once for the string literal, and once for the regex.

Another thing: Stay away from `\b`, the same with `\w`. `\b` is an anchor defined in terms of `\w` and `\w` is a character class that's pretty much useless for anything except quick one-off tasks where you have very tight control over everything you want to match. `\b` simply means that to one side of the anchor is a character matching `\w` and to the other side there isn't (either end of string or a character matching `\W`). Now, `\w` includes things like numbers, and `_`. If you search for vaguely word-like things at least *I* tend to not think of numbers and underscores as part of words. Oftentimes I like to make it explicit what it actually is what I'm looking for, e.g. via lookaround assertions: `(?<!\p{L})` is a way of specifying that there is no *letter* directly preceding the current point in the match, being effectively a replacement for `\b` at the start of the pattern. Likewise `(?!\p{L})` can be used for the `\b` at the end of the pattern. When writing them like this you have much more control about what you consider suitable "boundaries" for the things you're looking for, e.g. maybe you want to find `foo` only when it's bounded by whitespace: `(?<![^\S])foo(?![^\S])` (note the double negative here, because the lookahead and lookbehind can only be negative so they work also at the start and end of the string).

Comment: Ahh, of course! I thought I was making a stupid mistake somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the "Another thing" too! That makes sense